# docker-selenium on customized /etc/hosts file ?

Tags: selenium, docker, dns, selenium-chromedriver

I have an docker image that contains a maven selenium project, and it is to test on host "dev-mock.abc.com". Following is my docker command to trigger the selenium tests to be executed.

```
docker run --rm --privileged \
       --add-host="dev-mock.abc.com:123.45.67.89" \
       ${selenium-image}
```

What I have found is, during the runtime, the **/etc/hosts** of that container has been updated with this entry: "123.45.67.89 dev-mock.abc.com", but during the selenium execution, it still can not solve this "dev-mock.abc.com" name.

Does anyone know if selenium gets the customized entries in the /etc/hosts file, when it is being executed ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `/etc/nsswitch.conf` with correct content in your container is missing, so selenium "skips" `/etc/hosts` and is trying to use DNS. Try:

```
echo "hosts: files dns" > /tmp/nsswitch.conf
docker run --rm --privileged \
       --volume /tmp/nsswitch.conf:/etc/nsswitch.conf \
       --add-host="dev-mock.abc.com:123.45.67.89" \
       ${selenium-image}
```

Another option will be to edit `/etc/hosts` on your host OS and then use host OS networking for selenium container:

```
docker run --rm --privileged \
       --net=host \
       ${selenium-image}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. For this case, it was some other issue. After I dig deep into the host, I realize the same server, it works for firefox driver, but not for chrome one.  I have posted the question to chrome driver group and the problem has been solved. Thanks anyway for the help.